# Use of a leased/rented aircraft for business use and flown by a company employee

Tags: faa-regulations

I believe this is allowed under 91.501 but not sure what the definition of "operated by the company" is.

A pilot with ATP,MEL,MEI is employed by the company as its corporate pilot and paid a salary.

The pilot finds a twin engine aircraft owned by another company/individual that is not used in any commercial operation. A per hour dry rate has been establish for this aircraft.

The purpose of the flights is to fly company employees to meeting sites at multiple company locations.

Can the company pay the dry rate plus fuel for use of this aircraft?

Can the pilot operate this aircraft legally under part 91 based on compensation as a salaried employee?

Comment: If I understand the question, the company wants to dry-lease a plane so the corporate pilot can fly company personnel on company business. I wouldn't think that the fact that the corporate pilot is the one who found the plane and arranged the lease would have any more/less bearing on the legality than if someone who flies a desk for a living found the plane/arranged the lease. IANAL, but I _think_ that is how many/most corporate aircraft are operated today. Some are company _owned_, but I'd imagine the majority are _leased_.